# Lengths of intersection points of circumscribed circle with heights of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I want to proof this olympiad exercise:

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $K$ its circumscribed circle. Let $A^\prime$ be the intersection point of the height of $A$ on $|BC|$ with $K$, $B^\prime$ the intersection point of the height of $B$ on $|AC|$ with $K$ and $C^\prime$ the intersection point of the height of $C$ on $|AB|$ with $K$. Show that
> $$
> |AB^\prime|=|AC^\prime|, |BA^\prime|=|BC^\prime|, |CB^\prime|=|CA^\prime|.
> $$

Any hints on how to show this? I thought of showing congruence of the triangles $B^\prime AM$ and $MAC^\prime$ but I have no idea how to get one of the angles.

Comment: If you draw the extended altitudes and the hexagon with vertices $A$, $B$, $C$ and $A'$, $B'$, $C'$, many angles in the six sub-triangles are congruent to either $A$, $B$, or $C$. Convenient pairs of those angles get you to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess I solved it for myself. Let
$$
\angle AMC^\prime=\alpha, \angle B^\prime MA=\delta.
$$
We show that they are the same.
By periphery centriangle theorem we have
$$
2\gamma=\alpha, 2\beta=\delta
$$
whereby
$$
\gamma=\angle ACC^\prime
$$
and
$$
\beta = \angle B^\prime BA.
$$
If we show that $\gamma=\beta$, we have the congruences of the triangles and then the theorem follows directly. Now let $AB\cap CC^\prime = D$ and $AC\cap BB^\prime=E$, then we have two triangles with a right angle and one of them has the angle $\gamma$ and the other one $\beta$ but the third same angle that we call $\varepsilon$ is an angle of both triangles $CEA$ and $BDA$ so $\gamma=\beta$. $\square$